# How to generate secure private urls in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I like to create a secure URL for a user for his entries (delete and edit links).

for ex, this is my actual URL

```
http://localhost/project/blogs/delete/1/test-title
```

what i want to do is,

```
http://localhost/project/blogs/delete/4324143563443/test-title (some hash made of salt+user auth id)
```

My main purpose is to create a secure hash along with the URL for delete and edit method.
Is there any custom method's available? 
I searched in CakePHP Security functions http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html and not sure whether its the right way to do it or not sure which algorith to use)

Comment: Why are you doing this? So the user cannot see the id of the post they are about to delete? Generally speaking, you cannot un-hash a hash.

Comment: Only for delete and edit links i meant. So anyone user cannot delete or edit my post. Ofcourse, i can do that check in my controller itself, but, i want to make the URL look secure.

Comment: I can't say I can see a light at the end of the tunnel for this technique. You could pass a named param such as `http://localhost/project/blogs/delete/1/hash:4324143563443` but it wouldn't really serve much purpose. I personally would create a `roles` table and assign roles to users.

Comment: just found this: https://github.com/signified/CakePHP-Crypt-Component. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: You can use varchar(36) as a table's primary key data type.
Cakephp will generate UUID for the all new records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, although I am not quite clear on how/why you want to do this, it sounds like you want to "protect" these links through obscuring their URL's. This is known as "[Security through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)" and is generally frowned upon.

In Cake (and most apps), the usual way to achieve this is to allow users to login (see: [Auth Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)) and then, for example, in your delete action (i.e. for the URL /delete/1) requests would be checked for a valid user session, and that the user has sufficient permissions to delete.

Although I would strongly reccommend otherwise, if you did wish to create these obscure URLs then you should probably use [Security::hash();](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::hash). The problem with this is that you wouldn't be able to just hash the id and then determine the id from the hash directly (thats the whole point!). Instead you would need to store the hashes in the database and then query for the hash (each post could have a unique hash generated either from the id or just random data, either would do).

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned "Security by obscurity" isn't very smart. Nevertheless easiest way to achieve what you want is use UUID's for your table's primary key instead of numeric auto increment.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that whilst using UUID's would mean the sequence of primary keys was unpredictable, the "protected" URL would still be predictable from the "public" URL, which i'm fairly sure is what the OP want's to avoid. I think the easiest way to bind something unpredictable to each id would be by storing something (hash etc.) in the db.

Comment: Right. Anyways his approach is crappy in the first place so whatever way you generate the url it's not going to be truly secure :)