# How to create dynamic urls like www.example.com/x22bh1 using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have my CakePHP router set up like this-

`Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'p'));`

This results in the dynamic url **www.example.com/x22bh1** being routed to **www.example.com/posts/p/x22bh1**.

However my other urls that like **www.example.com/aboutus** or **www.example.com/register** etcetera are also routed to **www.example.com/posts/p/*** which is an unexpected behavior. Now to fix this I can define a regex based router. But for that to work, I'll need to specify all the exception pages that I don't want to get routed. So is there a way for both the features to work without specifying all the exception pages one by one in the router? Like if there is a controller and action for the URL then don't route but if there isn't then go to the default controller/action?

**www.example.com/x22bh1** => Controller `x22bh1` not found so route to **www.example.com/posts/p/x22bh1**.

**www.example.com/register** => Controller `register` with action `index` found so go to default page **www.example.com/register/index**

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090951/how-to-generate-secure-private-urls-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::connect('/register',array('controller'=>'register','action'=>'index'));  
Router::connect('/aboutus',array('controller'=>'aboutus','action' =>'index')); 
# Blind rule  
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'p'));
```

All other routes must be above this blind rule, otherwise all urls will be resolved in p action of posts controller. Means except defined routes all urls will be resolved in p action of posts controller and sequence will matter as I said earlier...

Comment: @Anubhav- you didn't read my question well. What I want is a way to not specifying all the exception pages like('/register', '/aboutus') one by one in the router and get it all working.